# OpenSSL (cpp) and .net RSA key exchange

Tags: .net, c++, openssl, key, rsa

I have a problem concerning OpenSSL and dotnet encryption. I would like to transform a RSA public and private key generated by OpenSSL into a dotnet one. This key is then used for further actions. For security reasons the usage of an external keystore or keyfile is not a solution. I have included a small part of an old cpp code I have to use and have marked two lines where I think it is possible to export the keys. The RSA key structure comes from an extenal PKI server. In fact the PKI server delivers an array of public keys for selected users when sending a message. The private key for each user is always stored local. Could one help me?

Thanks a lot for your help

Volker

```
############## start code ##############

typedef struct _KEY_POINT 
{
            unsigned short size;
            unsigned short key_size;
            unsigned long crc;
            unsigned char key_data[1];
} KEY_POINT, * PKEY_POINT;

unsigned char * encryptRSA( const unsigned char * pSrcBuffer,
                        unsigned long * pBufferSize,
                        const PKEY_POINT pPublicKey)
{
RSA * pRsa = NULL;
// -----snip ----------------
            unsigned char * pPublic_data = pPublicKey->key_data;
            pRsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey(&pRsa, (const unsigned char **)&pPublic_data, pPublicKey->key_size);
// Here chance to export *pRsa as .net public keye e.g. as string (base 64 encoded)
// -----snip ----------------
}

unsigned char * decryptRSA( const unsigned char * pSrcBuffer,
                        unsigned long * pBufferSize,
                        const PKEY_POINT pPrivateKey)
{
RSA * pRsa = NULL;
// -----snip ----------------
            unsigned char * pPublic_data = pPublicKey->key_data;
            pRsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&pRsa, (const unsigned char **)&pPublic_data, pPublicKey->key_size);
// Here chance to export *pRsa as .net private key e.g. as string (base 64 encoded)
// -----snip ----------------
}

############## end code ##############
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the data in DER format (I assume this since you use d2i_RSAXXX), maybe you can use the base64 function, http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/34/howto-base64-encode-with-cc-and-openssl/.

That also assumes .Net can read public and private keys in DER format.